# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' - Odoov8 to Odoov10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm still migrating some modules from v8 to v10 community.

I have these methods:

```
@api.multi
def _get_url(self): 

    url = self.env['seniat.url']
    url_ids = url.search['seniat.url'] 
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink.self.env.url_ids[1:] 
    url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse() 
    return url_obj 

@api.multi
def _get_url1(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.name

@api.multi
def _get_url2(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat

@api.multi
def _get_url3(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url()
    return url_obj.url_seniat2
```

These methods, call these fields:

```
url1 = fields.Char(
    string='URL1', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url1(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' fiscal information from partner')
url2 = fields.Char(
    string='URL2', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url2(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (RIF)')
url3 = fields.Char(
    string='URL3', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (CI or Passport)')
```

My view:

```
   <record id="view_wizard_url_seniat" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.wizard.seniat.url</field>
        <field name="model">wizard.seniat.url</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Update Url From Seniat" version="7.0">
                <separator string="URL Seniat for Partner Information" colspan="4"/>
                <field name="url1"/>
                <newline/>
                <separator string="URL Seniat for Retention Rate (Rif)" colspan="4"/>
                <field name="url2"/>
                <newline/>
                <separator string="URL Seniat for Retention Rate (CI or Passport)" colspan="4"/>
                <field name="url3"/>
                <separator string="Are you sure you want to do this?" colspan="4"/>
                 <group colspan="8" col="8">
                        <button icon="fa-book" name="update_url" string="Yes" type="object"/>
                        <button icon="fa-pencil-square-o" special="cancel" string="No"/>
                 </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

When I click on this button, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 41, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 69, in _get_url3
url_obj = self._get_url()
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 50, in _get_url
url_ids = url.search['seniat.url'] 
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I don't know if it's because I didn't place a `self.ensure_one()`. the error comes here: `url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse()` and `url_ids = url.search['seniat.url']`

Since it's a migration, there are still some points that might be buggy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling `search` method using square brackets.

Should be:

```
url.search(...)
```

When you use `['something']` you are trying to access method's item/property and a method does not have a `__getitem__` attribute to handle such call.

Comment: Just noticed that, Thank You very much